# updating a bunch of cells in google sheet using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

From the docs its understood that the following methods are good to get all the values of a sheet. Now I iterate and update the value in the list of dicts. How do i do in place update. Meaning update bunch of values after the processing is done. This would save lot of my time. I also found batch_update() but not sure how do i use this. Can someone help.

I am able to get all records as a list of dicts. Post that is my issue.

```
list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
list_of_dicts = worksheet.get_all_records()
```

Comment: here's the documentation of `batch_update` and it even provides an example:
https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_values#gspread.models.Worksheet.batch_update